# Jodd DbOomQuery hint with collection

Tags: java, jodd

I'm using [Jodd DbOom](http://jodd.org/doc/db/) to manage my queries and it's really awesome. But right now I'm are facing an undocumented situation.

I have a query that returns a list of objects(A), and each A has a list of objects (B), and each B is joined with other objects(C, D, E, etc). The problem is that the class `JoinHintResolver` doesn't set the values C, D, E on the B objects. The B objects are set correctly on the A objects.

Below is a test method to reproduce the error. The other used classes(`Girl`, `BadBoy`) are from Jodd test packages.

```
public void testHintsList() {
    Room room = new Room();
    Girl girl = new Girl();
    BadBoy badBoy = new BadBoy();
    Object[] data = new Object[] { room, badBoy, girl };

    JoinHintResolver jhr = new JoinHintResolver();
    Object[] result = jhr.join(data, "room, room.boys, room.boys.girl");
    assertEquals(1, result.length);
    assertTrue(result[0] instanceof Room);
    room = (Room) result[0];
    badBoy = room.getBoys().get(0);
    assertEquals(girl, badBoy.girl);
}

public class Room {
    private Long id;
    private List<BadBoy> boys;

    public Room() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public List<BadBoy> getBoys() {
    return boys;
    }

    public void setBoys(List<BadBoy> boys) {
    this.boys = boys;
    }
}
```

The documentation doesn't have any example like this, and Google neither. So I don't know if I did something wrong, or if Jodd wasn't prepared for this situation.

How could I set the hints so that Jodd would set the values correctly?

Comment: Nice question! I will try to make a testcase for you today to answer. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is the fact that you have a collection of `BadBoy`s in your `Room`. And the hint:

```
room.boys.girl
```

suggest they you want to inject a `Girl` instance into a *collection*. In java words, this is equivalent to:

```
getRoom().getBoys().setGirl(girl);
```

Obviously, since `getBoys()` returns a `List`, we can not set the `girl` property.

To test this what I've said, use the following hint instead:

```
room.boys[0].girl
```

This would inject the `girl` instance into the very first element of the list. Or, you can change your `Room` to have just a `Boy` property, instead of the list, and the original hint will work.

I hope this works for you :)

(see [test](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/commit/7084b8198926e06153467527ee3d500702515a72))

### EDIT

In [this branch](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/tree/hintsfix) I have something that looks like a fix :) Now you can write something like:

```
select $C{room.*}, $C{room.boys:boy.*}, $C{room.boys.girl:girl.*}
    from $T{Room room} join $T{Boy4 boy} on $room.id=$boy.roomId 
    join $T{Girl4 girl} on $boy.id=$girl.boyId 
    order by $room.id, $boy.id
```

And you can have the following model:

`Room` has list of `Boy`. Each `Boy` has one `Girl` assigned. When `entityAware` is on, this should work. Maybe you have time to test the branch?

Comment: The problem is that my model has a _one to many_ relationship from Room to BadBoy and another _one to many_ relationship from BadBoy to Girl. So,  your sugestions don't work for me. But if the hint `room.boys[0].girl` works, perhaps it would be easy to make `room.boys[CURRENT].girl` work. CURRENT meaning the index of the object being populated by the current row.

Comment: Yeah, got it; let me analyze what we can do :)

Comment: But for now the answer to this questions is: Jodd was not prepared for this - not yet! Thank you for this awesome example!

Comment: Hey @EduardoEdington can you send me just the outline of your DB schema (like which entity reference the other one?) Please send it to support at [jodd.org](http://jodd.org) - so to recreate it and correct it.

Comment: Hey @EduardoEdington maybe you can test the branch? See my edit.

Comment: Great news! I've just tested the branch and it worked. Many thanks for your attention, and now I'm waiting for the release version.

Comment: Great! No worries, @EduardoEdington, i will release the change soon - the current snapshots are stable, no worries ;)